# How to save muliplte excel sheets to desire location by today's date?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to save multiple excel sheets to desire folder by today's date and by cell value? How I can do it. So Let's say if I have 5 excel sheets with cell value A1 = "ABC" and so on. So I want to save these 5 excel sheets by today's date and cell value. these all data will be static.

I have run this code. It saves all sheets to the location but not by today's date and also save by cell value.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xcsvFile As String

For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    xcsvFile = "F\" & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
End Sub
```

I cannot able to save it.

Answer (score 1):

The original code you posted is riddled with syntax issues and also you never specify that you want today's date saved in the file name. Give the below a go. I made some comments to show you some of the issues you had.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()

    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String

    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'only move through the sheets in the workbook housing the code

        xcsvFile = "F:\" & xWs.Range("A1").Value & "_" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
        'xcsvFile = "F\" & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv" 'compare mine to yours to see issues

        xWs.Copy

        Dim newSheet As Workbook 'setting copied sheet to workbook variable for easier coding
        Set newSheet = ActiveSheet.Parent 'parent of worksheet is workbook

        newSheet.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        newSheet.Close False

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: reference to above code. Let's say If I have 5 sheets but I want to only save sheet 2  to sheet 5 and exclude the sheet 1. Can I save that way?

Comment: @jaydipdudhatra you can skip worksheets inside your loop by making sure the current sheets name does not equal some string [See here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351822/skip-one-worksheet-and-process-the-remaining-worksheets) (`If xWs.Name <> Sheet1 Then`). Please note that has nothing to do with your posted question. Separate questions should be researched and deserve a new question if unresolved rather tacked on as a follow up here :)

Comment: @jaydipdudhatra - I edited the post to save by the value inside cell "A1". Sorry, missed that key piece from before.

Comment: Thank you for the code. But Still one issue here. This all will be automatic. So When Excel will open it will automatically get the data copy the data and close itself. But the above code every time asks me to save the file. How I can skip that saving part. I need these files to be saved but silently without prompting. is it possible?

Comment: @jaydipdudhatra - see the argument i added to `newFile.Close`. This will skip that prompt. You can read more about that argument it to understand it fully.

Comment: One more question. How I can save all sheet except sheet1. I want to exclude it. Is there any way that I can exclude any file from saving it. ?

Comment: @jaydipdudhatra - since your new question is outside the scope of your original question, please create a new question. if you feel this answer *solved your original question as written* then mark it as answered.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you I will do it,